# How can I fix error "decompiled .class file bytecode version 52.0 (Java 8)

Tags: java, android

When I test my app on the emulator it works fine but when I ran the application on a real android 10.0 (Version) phone the log-cat shows errors which i can't understand at all. It is very confusing as it works fine on one phone (A lower version) and does not work on the other phone (Android 10.0 version).

The errors which I receive are the following:

Decompiled .class file, byte code version 52.00(Java 8) to be exact.

Logcat in error tab:

```
2020-02-18 22:08:23.114 22232-22280/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    Process: com.atmosphericproductiveinnovations.worldage, PID: 22232
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at bt.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):2)
        at bs.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):2)
        at bu.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):17)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ak.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):5)
        at ay.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):8)
        at ay.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):44)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000f6/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000f6/MapsDynamite.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at dalvik.system.DelegateLastClassLoader.loadClass(DelegateLastClassLoader.java:137)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at bt.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):2) 
        at bs.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):2) 
        at bu.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):17) 
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ak.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):5) 
        at ay.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):8) 
        at ay.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20104081@20.1.04 (120400-0):44) 
2020-02-18 22:08:23.128 22232-22232/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-02-18 22:08:23.206 22232-22232/? E/BufferQueueConsumer: disconnect by : com.atmosphericproductiveinnovations.worldage my_pid = 22232
```

MapsActivity.Java:

```
package com.atmosphericproductiveinnovations.worldage;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                    LatLng India = new LatLng(23.52, 78.59);
                   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                           .position(India)
                          .title("India"))
                            //.setSnippet("Meow. My name is");
        .setSnippet("Information-"+"" +
                "\n"+"Location:South Asia"+
                "\n"+"Population:133.92 crores (2017)"+
                "\n"+"GDP:2.6 lakh crores USD (2017):");

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(India));

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivity.this));
    }
}
```

Android manifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.atmosphericproductiveinnovations.worldage">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD7EYViNqAco_PXl-0CyCgJ6l2eEIzvTzY" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BaseDexClassLoader.class:

```
package dalvik.system;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class BaseDexClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    public BaseDexClassLoader(String dexPath, File optimizedDirectory, String librarySearchPath, ClassLoader parent) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    protected URL findResource(String name) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    protected Enumeration<URL> findResources(String name) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public String findLibrary(String name) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    protected synchronized Package getPackage(String name) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public String toString() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
}
```

DelegateLastClassLoader.class:

```
package dalvik.system;

import android.annotation.NonNull;
import android.annotation.Nullable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public final class DelegateLastClassLoader extends PathClassLoader {
    public DelegateLastClassLoader(String dexPath, ClassLoader parent) {
        super((String)null, (ClassLoader)null);
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public DelegateLastClassLoader(String dexPath, String librarySearchPath, ClassLoader parent) {
        super((String)null, (ClassLoader)null);
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public DelegateLastClassLoader(@NonNull String dexPath, @Nullable String librarySearchPath, @Nullable ClassLoader parent, boolean delegateResourceLoading) {
        super((String)null, (ClassLoader)null);
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public URL getResource(String name) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
}
```

I am new to IntelIJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you are using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0 or
>   below and your app is targeting API level 28 (Android 9.0) or above,
>   you must include the following declaration within the 
>   element of AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false" />
```

> This is handled for you if you are using
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0 and is not necessary
>   if your app is targeting a lower API level.

[specify requirement for apache http legacy library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library)

Comment: Do I  have to download some additional files like some sdk components of higher android version on my pc in order for my app to work on those versions. Because i downloaded an sdk for nougat and the app only works perfectly on that version and on 10.0 it shows this error.

Comment: Oh okay. Doing just that

Comment: @AtmosphereOfTech you always need to download some files like emulator images, the target sdk and build tools,... but it is not relevant to your current problem.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I am  loading the emulator. Taking decades to load

Comment: It says section app installation did not succeed in the emulator

Comment: Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
   The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
   Retry

Comment: I'm very sorry if I am not able to show the error properly.

Comment: @AtmosphereOfTech rebuild your app. in Android Studio from build menu click on `Rebuild`.

Comment: Okay i will rebuild it.

Comment: Till i am launching the emulator is there any other thing that might be the problem?

Comment: @AtmosphereOfTech you are testing in debug or signing in release mode?

Comment: @AtmosphereOfTech if you are in release mode check both v1 & v2. in debug or release uninstall your app from emulator before installation.

Comment: Yes, Thank you a lot. It works on 10.0(Real phone). Just in case in further(version) if the error comes what might be the problem?

Comment: Like app stops unfortunately. BTW where is the BaseDexClassLoader.class found?

Comment: Anyways Thank you a lot for fixing the problem for almost 50 minutes

Comment: @AtmosphereOfTech developers to support their apps always need to follow new Android release news. in new versions of Android we may have some changes that influence old apps.  you are using a legacy library (Apache) thus you should be more worried about this library.

Comment: for your app to work for newer version its better to use newer library than `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

maven clean helps me with this problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh2Fa.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).