# Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 52.0 (Java 8) Source for 'Android API 31 Platform' not found. Android

Tags: android

The following message was displayed at the top of the screen while using Android Studio.

[image]

[image]

When I selected Download , the following screen was displayed.

[image]

The emulator function was able to start, but this error still remains.
I don't know if it's a failure or an environment. It seems that there is no choice but to look at the situation for a while.

It is installed in "tools"-"SDK Manager"-"SDK Platform". The cause cannot be investigated.

[image]

I have tried to fix it with this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285943/how-can-i-fix-error-decompiled-class-file-bytecode-version-52-0-java-8), but it does not work for me.
Any suggestions ?